# Growth of a sequence defined recursively using binary digits

Tags: sequences-and-series

Define $a_n$ recursively as follows.  Let $a_1 = 1$, and given $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, let $a_{n+1}$ be the least positive integer $k > a_n$ such that the binary digits of $k$ in places $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are all zero.  So for instance, $a_1$ through $a_{10}$ are $$ 1,2,4,16,20,32,36,48,52,64,\ldots $$

**Question**: (roughly) How fast does $a_n$ grow?

It's easy to show that the set $A = \{a_n \;|\; n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ has asymptotic density zero (since the density of $A\setminus\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ is bounded above by $2^{-n}$).  This implies that $a_n$ grows faster than any linear function of $n$.  However, numerical tests suggest that $a_n$ grows slower than a quadratic.

**Question**: (precisely) Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/a_n$ converge?

Comment: Martin: I think I forgot to mention that $a_{n+1}$ is required to be greater than $a_n$.  So $a_4$ is the least integer greater than $4$ such that the first, second and fourth binary digits are zero.  This forces $a_4 = 16$.